# How can I debug php bin/console make:migration command freezing?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am developing a web app using Symfony. I have successfully been using console commands fine with my project. I must have done something because now the command `php bin/console make:migration` freezes, with no output even in verbose mode. The command `php bin/console make:entity` works fine and makes me think there is something wrong with the database connection. Steps I have tried:

- Make sure the DB version is present in .env file.
- Restarted server
- Deleted cache
- Deleted entire project and cloned from git and ran `composer install`

The app still works as intended, but I cannot make a migration. The command simply hangs with no errors. Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add different levels of verbosity using the parameter "-v", as the Console list explains:

> -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Launch `php bin/console make:migration -vvv` to debug and see why it hangs.

Comment: Ah thanks for this, I tried with -v, I didn't realize that you could -vvv

Answer (score 2):

It is not frozen. In this update, they have forgot to print the message.
The message is "Are you sure you wish to continue? y/i"

If you enter y and hit enter it will be continued.